# Make Mac boot upon plugging in power

Tags: startup, power, automation

I have a MacBook and I'd like it to boot automatically upon plugging it into a power source. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's really only designed to do that after a power-fail.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** It's just not designed to do this: it doesn't have the necessary hardware for lights-out management nor built in features.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to use the MacBook in "**docking mode**" (I don't know wether there is an official name for this), which works under these conditions:

- an external Display is connected
- the lid of the MacBook is closed
- the power supply is connected
- for usability's sake: have additional mouse & keyboard connected

Now when you disconnect the power source, the MacBook automatically goes to sleep. As soon as you reconnect the power source, it wakes up.

However I have only ever tried this with a booted MacBook, so I don't know if it works for a fully shut down device. I guess not, but it may be worth a try.